# Append output from external command with correct indentation

Tags: vim

I already know that I can do `:read !ls` to append the output of `ls` into my buffer. How about if I want to get the right indentation for the output?

Example: my buffer looks like

```
def foo
  # run :read !ls here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this by combining `<C-R>=` in insert mode with [`system()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system%28%29).

Move the cursor to the target position. Then enter insert mode and type:

```
<C-R><C-P>=system('ls')<Enter>
```

`<C-R><C-P>` represents the two key combos <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, one after the other. As soon as you follow this with `=`, the cursor drops down to a prompt where you enter `system('ls')` to complete the command.

That should do it.

The trick here is using `system()` in place of `:read!`: `system()` is a function, and therefore an expression, so we can combine it with the expression register in insert mode. See [`:h @=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#@=) for more info on this special register.

You may already be familiar with `<C-R>` in insert mode to insert the contents of some register. `<C-R><C-P>` is just like it but in addition it "fixes" the indent for you. Documentation is at [`:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P).

Comment: Sounds like this should work, but it doesn't. I'll dig more into `<C-R><C-P>`.

Comment: @VladtheImpala How does it not work? It's `<C-R><C-P>` in insert mode followed by `=`, then you get a prompt at the bottom where you can enter `system('ls')`. It works in my GVim, MacVim, terminal Vim.

Comment: I see the output from `ls`, it's just not properly indented.

Comment: @VladtheImpala Ok, but did you move the cursor to the target position, the `#` in your example?

Comment: Aha, doing that fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The most common way is to use `>` followed by some motion to indent the region and then simply repeat the indention via the `.` command.

- Do `:r!ls` to read in the output of the `ls` shell command.
- Move to the top of the output via `` `[ ``.
- Indent the output via `` >`] ``
- Simply repeat the indention with the `.` command until correct.

The `[` and `]` marks are set at the start and end of the last changed text respectively. In this case the output the `:r!ls` command.

For more help see:

```
:h `[
:h .
```

Comment: Do you mean use `>` followed by `.` manually? That's what I do now, I was hoping for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: `'[>']` to indent the output once, then do `.` as many times afterward to indent as needed. If you go to far then just undo via `u`. If you want to do this automatically I would suggest you look at @glts solution. However learning to how to use the redo/repeat command is a very useful tool to have in your vim bag of tricks.